# merging array of objects based on common property

Tags: javascript, object, merge

I need to merge two arrays of objects and I know there are many ways to do it but I am just curious what would be the best way to do it.

e.g - I have the following arrays,

```
array1 :[{ id :1, name : a, class :c1}, {id :2, name :b, class :c2}]
array2 :[{ id:1, score :20}, {id:2, score :30}]
```

what i want is

```
array3 :[{id :1, name :a, score :20}, {id:2, name:b, score: 30}]
```

EDIT :
tried code

```
for(var ind1  in array1){
       for(var ind2 in array2){
           if(array1[ind1].id  == array2[ind2].id){
              array1[ind1].score = array2[ind2].score;
                            }
                     }
               }
```

array1 gives me the required array

Comment: "what i want is"... and what have you already tried yourself? Please post your code.

Comment: If you already know how to do it, this isn't a question for stackoverflow. Instead, you should post your completed code on codereview.stackexchange.com. That site is designed for improving working code.

Comment: I am just looking for a better way to do it. the current code has a complexity of n * m.

Comment: @forgivenson This would be considered as "example code", which is off-topic for Code Review. There's no context in this code. Unlike SO, CR does not want the context to be stripped away.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it. I would probably add some other conditionals to prevent errors if there was a mismatch of id's but in basic this is the principal.

```
array1 = [{ id :1, name : "a", class :"c1"}, {id :2, name :"b", class :"c2"}];
array2 = [{ id:1, score :20}, {id:2, score :30}];


var length1 = array1.length;
var length2 = array2.length
var array3 = [];

for( var i = 0; i < length1; i++){ 

    joined = {id: array1[i].id, name: array1[i].name};

        for(var j = 0; j < length2; j++){ 


        if(array2[j].id == array1[i].id){ // Check if the id's match.

            joined.score = array2[j].score; // If the match add score.
            break;

        }else{ 

            continue; // If they don't move on.

        }

        array3[i] = joined; // Add to output array.

    }

}


console.log(array3);
```

Here is a fiddle to show it.

http://jsfiddle.net/k7Lv7ub9/